# Is the following sentence correct - "usage of apprehending"?

Tags: sentence-construction

Thus, you reduce the risk of any software changes by apprehending the possible cause.

Comment: We could do better with a bit more context... But I have a hunch that a. ist used here as either "anticipating" or "understanding": http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/apprehend -> 2. or 3.

Comment: swapping 'apprehend' to 'comprehend' would lessen the possibility it meant understand. I also doubt is means 'arrest' so I'm left with the possibility that it might need 'anticipate' or even 'obviate'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right! *apprehending something* is possible.

The word is used correctly but **it's old-fashioned.**

OALD has an entry like that

> [*apprehend something*](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/apprehend)

To avoid complexity, you may simply come up with other options. Maybe...

> Thus, you reduce the risk of any software changes by *knowing/understanding/recognizing* the possible cause.